# Convert JSON to .plist

Tags: ios, json, plist

I have a JSON file that I exported from a web service. I need to convert this to a .plist file that I can import into the main bundle of an iOS app. What's the easiest way to do this?

Note - the app doesn't need to grab the JSON from a server or anything. This is a one-time conversion that I need to do. The app will always just use the plist. I just need to know how to convert it.

Answer (score 85):

I'd recommend plutil on the command line.

```
plutil -convert xml1 in.json -o out.plist
```

It will blow up with NULL values in dictionaries and some other inconsistencies that iOS JSON deserialization will handle more gracefully, but it does appear to work pretty well.

Answer (score 20):

I have a web app to convert data between JSON and PList:

https://github.com/fengchang/json2plist

Answer (score 2):

David's answer works pretty well, but as a Ruby lover I've written a very simple tool to do the same with ruby: https://github.com/javiertoledo/json2plist

Answer (score 0):

another online converter JSON to PList
https://wtools.io/convert-json-to-plist